# Как скопировать и сразу преобразовать данные из одной таблицы в другую mysql innodb?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Для обычного копирования данных таблицы использую

```
INSERT INTO `table_1`(`row_1`, `row_2`, `row_3`) SELECT `row_1`, `row_2`, `row_3` FROM `table_2`;
```

Но в этот раз надо преобразовать данные при копировании. В исходной таблице есть поле bdate с датой рождения в формате date (0000-00-00), в новой таблице есть поля year, month и day. Можно ли одним запросом перелить из одной таблицы данные в другую, чтобы дата из поля bdate логически разбилась по полям year, month, day? Спасибо.

Comment: разумеется можно. сначала сделайте запрос, который возвращает данные в нужном вам виде. потом допишите перед ним insert. для выделения частей из даты можно использовать соответствующие функции, вроде year(). http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Date_and_time_functions.html  А вообще хранить части даты в разных полях не хорошо. все запросы для работы с ними усложняются, а о сравнении на больше меньше лучше вообще забыть при этом. тип date специально сделан для хранинея и удобной работы с датами

Comment: Спасибо, да, что-то туго соображаю, не буду так делать...